# Insert INT into MySql table via label in Java - NumberFormatException

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert an Int to a table, via label. So I have 6 columns, starting with Name, Lastname as varchars, and Number, Points, Assists and Rebounds as ints. Query with:

```
String sql = ("INSERT INTO `PlayerTable`(`Name`, `Lastname`, `Number`, `Points`, `Assists`, `Rebounds`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        PreparedStatement ps = PlayerBase.get().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, playerNameFld.getText());
        ps.setString(2, playerLNFld.getText());
```

works just fine, but when I try to parse:

```
try {
            ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(playerNumberFld.getText()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get an *NumberFormatException: For input string: ""* and *SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3*.
How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Your `playerNumberFld` is empty.

Comment: You wouldn't get a SQLException if you didn't have a catch block for your `setInt` call... which you shouldn't. (If you fail to set a parameter properly, surely you don't want to continue with the SQL statement...)

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
            ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(playerNumberFld.getText()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ps.setInt(3,0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

playerNumberFld is empty. So If you try to parse exception comes. So Incase of exception you just put 0 in catch block and try

Comment: Unconditionally? Whatever the value is? That sounds like a bad idea to me. It would usually be better to check for valid input earlier, and then if anything goes wrong at the point where the SQL statement is being prepared, let that exception propagate. (I wouldn't catch `Exception` anyway, personally...)

Comment: But can someone explain to me, how playerNumberFld is empty when I enter a value in it?

Comment: Ok so I checked if value is correct != null for Integer and then executed query and it works. Thanks.